# Equality in Reisz Rearrangement

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

For $f,g,h$ nonnegative and vanishing at infinity (i.e., measurable and $\mu(\{|f|>t\})<\infty$ for all $t$) define
$$
I(f,g,h)=\int \int f(x)g(x-y)h(y)dxdy.
$$
Define the symmetric decreasing rearrangement $f^\star$ by
$$
f^\star=\int_0^\infty \chi_{\{f>t\}^\star}(x)dt,
$$
where for any set $A$ we define $A^\star$ to be the ball centered at the origin with volume equal to $\mu(A)$.

I want to find $f,g,h$ such that $I(f,g,h)=I(f^\star,g^\star,h^\star)$.

I have tried the following examples and found an inequality:
$$
f=x \chi_{[0,1]}(x),\quad g=x \chi_{[0,2]}(x),\quad h=x\chi_{[0,3]}(x).
$$
In this case $I(f,g,h)=\frac{1}{30}$ and $I(f^\star,g^\star,h^\star)$ was around $2.26$ by WolframAlpha. I also tried
$$
f=x\chi_{[0,1]}(x), \quad g=-x\chi_{[-1,0]}(x), \quad h=\left(\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\chi_{[-1,1]}(x).
$$
Here $I(f,g,h)=\frac{1}{30}$ and $I(f^\star,g^\star,h^\star)=\frac{17}{240}$.

Any examples for which equality does hold would be greatly appreciated.